# JasperReports Jackson dependency conflict

Tags: java, maven, jackson, jasper-reports, dropwizard

I am using JasperReports 6.3.1 with a Dropwizard 1.0.5 project and it seems to have a conflict with Jackson when desalinizing my JSON response.

I am getting:

```
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
....
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException
```

and

```
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
...
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.el.JspELException
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.getConfig()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationConfig;
```

I tried excluding `jackson-core` from my Maven dependency but it won't do the trick.
As I see, Jasper uses 2.1.4 and Dropwizard uses 2.7.8

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Did you check the full dependency tree? What changed after adding exclusion?

Comment: When excluding from pom.xml, the dependencies tree seemed untouched and I got the same error. When excluded the library from the dependencies tree, I started getting _java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem.
The issue was that as I was using a Dropwizard application (v 1.0.5), which was coming with jackson 2.7.8.

JasperReports is also using jackson, but it uses 2.1.4.

When deserializing the JSON objects, it was using JasperReports's library (v 2.1.4) which didn't have all the needed functions.

I solved this by adding the jackson library (core and annotations) in my pom.xml.

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Objectreader` class is present in jackson-databind binary.

can you try to excluding jackson-databind and not jackson-core-asl.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```